# Update data in the same row

Tags: mysql, sql

Got problems getting this works.
I have a table named trip_cost

```
__________________________________
trip_id | account | details| cost|
----------------------------------
T001    |trip     |train   |30   |
T001    |stay     |hotel   |50   |
T001    |food     |lunch   |20   |
T002    |trip     |train   |40   |
T002    |stay     |hotel   |20   |
T002    |food     |lunch   |50   |
----------------------------------
```

I want to update column cost where `trip_id` is `T002` to cost where `trip_id` is `T001`.

I tried this query:

```
UPDATE trip_cost
SET cost= (SELECT cost WHERE trip_id = 'T001')
WHERE trip_id = 'T002'
```

The query affected 3 rows, but it update all T002 costs to 0.
How can I solve this problem with minimum queries?

Comment: You're talking about updating T002 but your where uses T004

Comment: 1. you are missing from clause 2. there is more that 1 record with id as T001. 3. You will need to wrap the subquery with an outer query.

Comment: @Fleury26 My bad, edited it. I want to change all the cost to T001 cost. But I can't get it works.

Comment: @isaace I'm sorry, I didn't get what you describe, new to mysql and this is a task my teacher gave me.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying for a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE trip_cost
    SET cost= (SELECT cost FROM trip_cost WHERE trip_id = 'T001')
WHERE trip_id = 'T002';
```

That won't work in MySQL because you cannot reference the table being updated in a subquery (like that).  At least this query expresses the logic correctly.

Instead, use a `join`:

```
UPDATE trip_cost tc JOIN
       trip_cost tc1
       ON tc1.trip_id = 'T001'
    SET tc.cost= tc1.cost
WHERE tc.trip_id = 'T002';
```

Why doesn't the first work?  Well, it is equivalent to:

```
UPDATE trip_cost tc
    SET tc.cost= (SELECT tc.cost WHERE tc.trip_id = 'T001')
WHERE tc.trip_id = 'T002';
```

That is, the references are all to the outer query.  Because `trip_id` has to have the value `'T002'`, it cannot also have the value `'T001'`.  Hence, the `NULL` assignment.